# How to get duplicate value from one column in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following record in a table:

```
id | Name | 

1  | abc 
2  | bac
3  | abc
4  | cab
5  | abc
6  | abc
7  | cab
8  | cab
9  | cab
```

I would like to retrieve only records with 'abc' entries. How do I construct a query to accomplish this?

Here's an example output illustrating what I mean:

```
1  | abc 
3  | abc
5  | abc
6  | abc
```

Comment: Select * from YourTable Where Name = 'abc'

Comment: i know but this table data are coming randomly. @JithinShaji

Comment: What ever it is, If you use a SELECT with that WHERE condition, we will get the desired Out put.

Comment: What do you mean with "randomly"? What is the difference between the output and your desired output?

Comment: some of them is `WHERE`, not randomly is `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
WHERE Name = "abc";